# tampermokey script only runs 1 time

Tags: javascript, click, tampermonkey

I have a tampermonkey script that runs on a video play list.  It should run on each playlist I click on, but it only runs on the first playlist and I have to close chrome and repopen it to get it to work on a new playlist.

```
var playlistmax = document.querySelectorAll('.PlaylistVideo').length;
var i = 1;

setInterval( function () { 
  document.getElementsByClassName('PlaylistVideo')[i].click();
  alert ("I is : " + i);
  i++;             
}, 42000);
```

On the first play list the alert popup and tells me I (what video it's on).  But after the first playlist I get no alerts.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I've noticed that if I let it just run after the playlist (5 videos total) is done I get these alerts for I in this order: 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 6 2 2 2 7 3 3 3 8 ... and so on.

Comment: The script is inserted in all `iframe` elements. Use [`@noframes` meta key](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_noframes).

Comment: @wOxxOm adding the '@noframes' to the script disabled the script and it did nothing at all.

Comment: Well, your question doesn't provide a complete picture so, unless you make it more specific, all we can do is shoot in the dark. Maybe the playlist is in the iframe. Maybe the page/frame is reloaded by the page script. Maybe it even clears the timers it didn't set. Or something else.

Comment: @wOxxOm .  There are Iframes on the page, but the video playlist is not in one .  I first set works fine so I know it's something the the  var I   the alerts tell me it's reseting but also that it keeps counting (see above).  I was thinking that maye I need to make it a globel var but I don't know if that would do it and if so how to do it and reset it when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tampermonkey script is reseting on page load. that's why i is always 1